# SSH server supporting custom authentication?

Tags: ssh

We currently provide customer access to files using FTP.   We  need to replace this with a more secure solution. We don't want to deal with the secondary secured channel required for FTPS, and are looking to use an SSH server for SFTP.

The FTP implementation we are using is Pure-FTPD (https://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd).  Pure-FTPD allows customized authentication via a plugin. Basically, you write a wrapper around your own auth methods that respond "yes" or "no" when presented with username/password tokens.

We have implemented a Pure-FTPD wrapper around an internal authentication API that determines if a user can access the FTP server, and are looking for the same option in an SFTP server.

Is there a Linux-compatible SSH/SFTP server that allows custom authentication so that we can continue to use our internal authentication API?

Comment: This strikes me as exactly the sort of thing that PAM is supposed to do.  Or are you looking only for product recommendations (hint: trick question)?

Comment: Not really looking for product recommendations so much as a list of products which I can use as a starting point for my own analysis.  I realize recommendations are frowned upon in stackexchange, and there is a fine line between a list and recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PAM to authenticate in OpenSSH, just write PAM module for your systems.

Comment: I'm not sure your answer adds much more than my comment; any chance you could flesh it out a bit, perhaps give a small example of how to do this?

Comment: Regarding PAM, seems like it has a lot of overhead - write a plugin in C, register with PAM, etc.   I was hoping for something higher level, like exec'ing a script that returned text or an exit code.

Comment: @MadHatter It is the same, but my answer was posted before your comment :D

Comment: Actually, my comment was posted a minute *before* your answer.  But apart from that, I agree with you.

Comment: @lreeder It's true that PAM module is not so easy to write as some ten-lines-script, but it is the right way how to do it. You can look over if there is not already existing PAM module for your auth. system.